# Create Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> using refelction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, reflection

I have some Display Templates in my ASP.NET MVC project. Right now i can use them like so:

```
@Model MyModel

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PropertyName)
```

What I'd like to do is just loop through the object graph and do this dynamically:

```
@Model MyModel

foreach(var property in MyModel.GetType().GetProperties()){
    @Html.DisplayFor(/*Any way to do this?*/)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... I had a text example, but the problem is that the DisplayFor method is generic too... that makes it tricky...

Comment: It'll be *along the lines of* `var param = Expression.Parameter(MyModel.GetType());
foreach(var property in MyModel.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(
               param, property), param));
}` - but with some MakeGenericMethod in the middle. Is it really worth this level of pain?

Comment: NO. :) thanks... would be if we had more display templates to run through but i'd rather do it by hand... mind - this is going to bug me now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/02/09/asp-net-mvc-complex-object-modelmetadata-issue.aspx

with thanks to Jeremy Skinner for finding that for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this is exactly what `DisplayForModel` already does:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel(yourModel);
```

Comment: it does but the answer i posted makes it work with complex/nested types :)